# reversed cookie name and value

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I need to get an assignement done for a web programming class where I need to use php to create a "remember the milk type' of application and right now I'm trying to solve my cookie/session issues.  I'm also using firebug to inspect it and it's showing the name as the value and the value as the cookie name.  Furthermore, I have to read a form for the username/password data and then pass that to the cookie to be saved.  This is the code related to the cookie in my .php

```
label>Username :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" 
 type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<?php
setcookie($username,'username');
setcookie($password,'password');

?>
```

I know this sounds like remedial question and I hate having to waste your guys' time but I don't know where else to look.   I also have a sesssionstart() a the top of the page and I have a question about that.  I understand to declare a session variable I need to call $_SESSION = name, but does this work like a cookie but the data is saved on the server or what?
 Can someone also clearly explain how sessions work?

Comment: use `session_start()` instead of `sesssionstart()`

Comment: to declare a session variable `$_SESSION['user']=$username;` not `$_SESSION = name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session variables get stored in the server and could not get manipulated by client. Cookies on the other hand are stored in client side and are easily accessible and not safe (unless encrypted).
session variables will persist throughout the session and once you close that session (usually logout or timeout) they are lost.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between cookies and sessions is that cookies are stored in the user's browser, and sessions are not. This difference determines what each is best used for.

A cookie can keep information in the user's browser until deleted. If a person has a login and password, this can be set as a cookie in their browser so they do not have to re-login to your website every time they visit. You can store almost anything in a browser cookie.

he trouble is that a user can block cookies or delete them at any time. If, for example, your website's shopping cart utilized cookies, and a person had their browser set to block them, then they could not shop at your website.

Sessions are not reliant on the user allowing a cookie. They work instead like a token allowing access and passing information while the user has their browser open. The problem with sessions is that when you close your browser you also lose the session. So, if you had a site requiring a login, this couldn't be saved as a session like it could as a cookie, and the user would be forced to re-login every time they visit.

You can of course get the best of both worlds! Once you know what each does, you can use a combination of cookies and sessions to make your site work exactly the way you want it to.